# Extract implementer when inheritance hierarchy in C++

Tags: c++

**Edit** Made clear() and append() public in "ProductionNode"

---

I am trying to implement in C++ a similar example to the one presented at "Working effectively with Legacy code" page 359, the resulting diagram class at page 361.

It uses multiple inheritance; there is a base class "ProductionNode" which fully implements an interface called "Node", a second base class called "ProductionModelNode" which inherits from "ProductionNode" and from another interface called "ModelNode" which in turns inherits from the"Node" interface.

When I try to instantiate "ProductionModelNode" compiler claims that the methods defined at "Node" are not implemented, however they are implemented at "ProductionNode".

```
#include<algorithm>
#include <string>

class Node
{
public:
  virtual void clear() = 0;
  virtual void append(const std::string&) = 0;
};


class ProductionNode : public Node
{
public:
  virtual void clear() override
  {
    m_name.clear();
  }

  virtual void append(const std::string& suffix) override
  {
    m_name += suffix;
  }

protected:
  std::string m_name;
};


class ModelNode : public Node
{
public:
  virtual void reverse() = 0;
  virtual void uppercase() = 0;
};


class ProductionModelNode : public ModelNode, public ProductionNode
{
public:

  virtual void reverse() override
  {
    std::reverse(std::begin(m_name), std::end(m_name)); 
  }

  virtual void uppercase() override
  {
    std::transform(m_name.begin(), m_name.end(), m_name.begin(), ::toupper);
  }

private:
  int m_age;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  ProductionModelNode mn;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about which function should `(ModelNode&)(mn).clear()` call. `clear` is not implemented in `ModelNode`, and `ProductionNode`, where it is implemented, is unrelated to `ModelNode`.

Comment: @rabedad: Do not add **solved**, but instead, vote/accept answers ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of Dreadful Diamond on Derivation.

The class `ProductionModelNode` has two `Node` parent, one from `ProductionNode` is implemented, but the other from `ModelNode` is not.

Possible "trial" solutions:

- Remove the inheritance from `ModelNode`
- Implement `clear` and `append` in `ProductionModelNode`
- Use virtual inheritance

Example using virtual inheritance:

```
class ProductionNode : virtual public Node
...
class ModelNode: virtual public Node
```

Comment: Yes using virtual inheritance solves it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a method with `= 0` sign (for example: `virtual void reverse() = 0;`) it means that the method defined to be **Pure virtual**.

You **must** implement every "Pure virtual" method in every class that derive from the class that contains the "pure virtual" methods. (in your case `Node` class).

`class ProductionModelNode : public ModelNode, public ProductionNode
{
public:
    ...
    virtual void clear() override {
        //implementation 
    }
    virtual void append(const std::string&) override {
        //implementation 
    }
    ...
}`